# I want to see 8 EEG values using mindwave mobile 2 and Hc-05

Tags: hc-05

I want to see 8 EEG values using mindwave mobile 2 and Hc-05

But, I have only the most basic connection

If I run it in this state and look at it from the serial monitor, the value comes out weird
Below is the code I wrote and the value I get

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BT(11, 10);  //Rx/Tx

void setup() {
  BT.begin(38400);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (BT.available()) Serial.write(BT.read());
  if (Serial.available()) BT.write(Serial.read());
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNOAK.png)

How can we view this value in numerical form and graph?
Please help me...

I want to see 8 EEG values using mindwave mobile 2 and Hc-05`your text`